# XML info for my computer installing Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, xml

I'm new to this.  Where do I find my computer's info to replace this generic XML data?

```
<property>
    <name>dfs.datanode.data.dir</name>
    <value>file:///home/hduser/hdfs/datanode</value>
    <description>DataNode directory</description>
</property>

<property>
    <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
    <value>hdfs://10.0.1.1/</value>
    <description>NameNode URI</description>
</property>
```

http://www.elcct.com/installing-hadoop-2-3-0-on-ubuntu-13-10/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the tutorial you are following, there was a step where you created these folders:

> We should create and prepare directories for our data:
>
> ```
> mkdir -p ~/hdfs/namenode
> mkdir -p ~/hdfs/datanode
> mkdir $HADOOP_INSTALL/logs
> ```

The folder `~/hdfs/datanode` (which is actually `/home/hduser/hdfs/datanode`) was created for the purpose of holding the Hadoop data, so you should use that as the value under the property `dfs.datanode.data.dir`.

The `fs.defaultFS` is the IP address or hostname of your NameNode (the "main" computer) in your Hadoop cluster. You should already know which machine will be acting as your NameNode, so put its IP address or hostname there.

Comment: Thank you!  Seems to be working. Applying to the other nodes.